# jQuery's chosen plugin on dropdownlists looks odd?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, jquery-chosen

I'm using the jQuery plugin chosen and I believe I've done everything correctly however my asp.net drop down list's width is so small that I don't see the results.

First I added a reference to the libraries:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="Chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>`

I included the CSS:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="Chosen/chosen.css" />`

Then I applied the class to my drop down:

```
  <asp:DropDownList class="chosen-select" ID="ddlEmps" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                            ToolTip="Select the employee." 
                            onselectedindexchanged="ddlEmps_SelectedIndexChanged" >
```

Finally in document ready I `.chosen()` it:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".chosen-select").chosen();
        });
```

Here is the html markup in the browser:

[image]

The markup is basically:

```
<select name="ddlEmps" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ddlEmps\',\'\')', 0)" id="ddlEmps" title="Select the employee." class="chosen-select" style="display: none;">
    <option value="2661">Jon</option>
    <option value="2987">Joe</option>
    <option value="3036">Steve</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="68">Mark</option>
</select>
```

Here is what it looks like visually:

[image]

I believe it is applying chosen correctly as the css is there, there are no browser issues in the console (chrome / ff / ie).  I can even start typing things and the results get smaller, I just cant see the results?

### Update

The only thing I did notice is if I have a `DropDownList` that I do not have a class `chosen-select` on it (basically a plain old asp.net dropdownlist) and not applying chosen to it in document ready or window onload...if I just apply `.chosen()` to it during the console it appears correctly for instance here's a simple dropdownlist without applying `.chosen`:

[image]

So it looks correct...if I now go to the console section (google chrome) and just do:

`$("#ddlEREmployees").chosen();`

That is just directly in the console I type that in then it works as shown:

[image]

But of course I still need to make this work without having to go to the console and doing this...

### Update 2

I looked at the rendered html and it is producing a width:0px but I'm not sure where its coming from:

`<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 0px;" title="Select the employee." id="ddlEtimeEmps_chosen"><a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1"><span>Jon</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chosen-drop"><div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off"></div><ul class="chosen-results"></ul></div></div>`

Notice the section

`style="width: 0px;"`

When I check google chrome it doesnt reference a .css file...it just says:

Styles and under that I see:

```
element.style {
 width: 0px;
}
```

Where could this be coming from?  And how can I remove it?

Comment: When do you fill the dropdown list values?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward - This is asp.net webforms so on page load.

Comment: Try use $(window).load(function(){ instead of domready

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward - I dont believe this is the issue, its not that it is not working...as mentioned I can actually filter the results as I type into the `chosen` drop down.  The issue is I do not see the results...

Comment: I think that chosen init is fired before the pageload completeness so the width is with the empty control; try using windows.load for init chosen.

Comment: I tried the following `<script type="text/javascript">

        $(window).load(function () {
            alert("hi");
            $("#ddlConcertoCommissions").chosen();
        });
    </script>` same issue (different drop down I tried it on...However what I did notice happen is if I go to a console window on a drop down that does not have the class `chosen-select` and inside of the console window just enter in `$("#myDropDownID").chosen();` then this works fine, I can see the drop down results...but if I add it in dom ready or window load I cannot see the results :(.

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward any ideas on my comment?

Comment: Try to execute $(".chosen-select").trigger("liszt:updated"); at the end of your windows load?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward - same issue, the chosen is applied but I cannot see the results.  This is with a drop down whose `class=chosen-select`. ???

Comment: A sample fiddle works http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/cFdwH/; I  think is a timing issue, for that I asked when the drop downs are filled, try pageLoad see: http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward Right that is fine, however, this is not working for me based on all the other jquery etc...so maybe my thought was (and see my update above in bold) that there is something causing this....

Comment: Also the issue is that my issue is not that its not working...it works as pictured in the screen shot.  The issue is the size of the drop down is small I cannot even read what it says, again see the post with picture...

Comment: Dear Friends, I am also having problem with chosen plugin. Please can any one have a look on my problem "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41395275/asp-dropdownlistchosen-not-showing-any-items-in-the-dropdown"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to play with the jquery and remove the style...

`$(".chosen-select").chosen(); $('.chosen-container').css('width', '');`

This removed the CSS style I described in my initial question.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. I have `$("#controlId").chosen();` in the document ready. But the asp.net dropdown is invisible first. So I tried Irvin's suggestion, but that did not work. I am also curious what caused the width: 0px; I can verify that `$('.chosen-container').css('width', '');` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Is your chosen control initially hidden (example inside a popup conatiner)?

If so try use:

```
.chosen-select {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

or some related css fix suggested in the following links; at the moment no final fix is released.

Github issues:
https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/92 and https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/795

Answer (score 0):

TRy using

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({width: 10em;});
```

May be some css issue. TRy debugging css styles applied on the final choden div.

Comment: This is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I had the 0 width problem when I was using the 'chosen-select' inside of a tab.
Had to add in this code when switching to that tab.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought maybe someone else might find this helpful, since we use Chosen in our webforms app.

1. You need to set the width when you instantiate Chosen onto your dropdown/listbox, if the dropdown/listbox isn't visible when the page loads.  For example, we have popup dialogs that aren't displayed on page load.  They are shown when the user clicks a button/icon.
2. We use EndRequestHandlers in our js to handle postbacks.  Sometimes we have to set the width and instantiate Chosen again.  Here is an example:

$(function() {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);

```
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {

}

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    if (args.get_error() == undefined) {
        var postBack = sender._postBackSettings;
        var postBackClass = postBack.sourceElement.className;

        if (postBack == null || postBack.sourceElement == null || postBackClass == null || postBackClass == "") {
        }
    }

    $('#filter-container select').chosen({ width: "100px", disable_search_threshold: 10, no_results_text: "Item Not Found" });

}
```

});

3. Chosen isn't robust enough to know that it's already being applied from another call somewhere else.  So be mindful of the selectors you pick to apply the Chosen plugin to it.  It's better to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If the chosen field id within a popup, try this css. This worked for me.

```
.chosen-container.chosen-container-multi {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that I ran across.

```
AbstractChosen.prototype.container_width = function () {
      var getHiddenOffsetWidth = function (el) {
        // save a reference to a cloned element that can be measured
        var $hiddenElement = $(el).clone().appendTo('body');
        // calculate the width of the clone
        var width = $hiddenElement.outerWidth();
        // remove the clone from the DOM
        $hiddenElement.remove();
        return width;
      };
      if (this.options.width != null) {
        return this.options.width;
      } else {
        return "" + (($(this.form_field).is(":visible"))
        ? this.form_field.offsetWidth
        : getHiddenOffsetWidth(this.form_field)) + "px";
      }
};
```