# asp DropDownListChosen not showing any items in the dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, jquery-chosen

I've currently added chosen jquery plugin to my asp project via nuget.

```
Install-Package DropDownListChosen
```

then in one of the aspx page I've used the dropdown as

```
// asp conent page
<asp:DropDownListChosen ID="listBoxAddress" runat="server"
    NoResultsText="No results match." Width="350px"
    DataPlaceHolder="Type Here..." AllowSingleDeselect="true">
</asp:DropDownListChosen>

// code behind
public void GetAddress()
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        listBoxAddress.ClearSelection();
        listBoxAddress.Items.Clear();
        DAL_Customer_Registration objDAL = new DAL_Customer_Registration();
        dt = objDAL.Get_Address();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            listBoxAddress.Items.Add(new ListItem(row["ADDRESS"].ToString(), row["ID"].ToString()));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

In my master page I've added the .css of the chosen plugin

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" type="text/css" href="~/chosen.css" />
```

But still the items of the dropdown are not showing. Why is it so? What is wrong with my process? What else references should I have to add in master page or asp content page? As suggested, I've already installed the dependencies jquery files still I am getting error as "`Uncaught TypeError: this.container.find(...).first is not a function`" in the chosen.jquery.js file.

Is there any mistake with my code? Please suggest the possible solutions. Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you included the jquery reference or is it not required? What about the console errors, you might get something these if it's not working as intended? And what browser are you testing this on?

Comment: Are you sure the `DataTable` in `GetAddress()` has rows or does not throw an error (they are caught but not handled)? Try to add some ListItems on the aspx page for testing.

Comment: DropDownListChosen have a jquery Dependencies, According to [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DropDownListChosen/).

Comment: Thanks to you all for your reply. I've elaborated my problem. Please help.